# C# Replace expression matching start end

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Can anyone help me do a replace in a string in C# of any any string starting with "startingChars" and ending with "endingChars"...something like that:

```
Regex.Replace(strToReplaceIn, "startingChars[anyNumberOfChars]endingChars", myFunction(anyNumberofChars));
```

where strStartingChars and strEndingChars are two strings and myFunction is defined

for example, if a starting is `"Hello, I need to replace startingCharsWITH_SOMETHINGendingChars, ...."` the result to be: `"Hello, I need to replace myFunctionResult("WITH_SOMETHING"), ..."`

Please, let me know the Regex.Replace expression that will help, the problem is not finding the matching expression, but the replacing...how can I refer to

```
anyNumberOfChars
```

in the replacement parameter of the expression?

I hope it's clear enough...Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a named group to easily get the contents to replace, and a match evaluator to construct the replacement string:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string strToReplaceIn = "Hello, I need to replace startingCharsWITH_SOMETHINGendingChars, ....";
        string replaced = Regex.Replace(strToReplaceIn, "startingChars(?<contents>.*?)endingChars", (match) => {
            return "myFunctionResult(" + match.Groups["contents"].Value + ")";
        });
    }
}
```

A [named group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) (the `(?<contents>.*?)` bit in the expression) is something that lets you refer to a subpart of the expression, which I think is what you are asking for.
Alternatively, you could use a simple group , i.e. just an expression between parenthesis, without the `?<name>` part: `(.*)`. Then, you should refer to it with an integer index:

```
match.Groups[1].Value
```

(Note: Groups[0] represents the whole match)

Comment: that's exactly want I needed...Thank you very much, some remark:     `{return "myFunctionResult(" + match.Groups["contents"].Value + ")"; }` become form me `myFunction(match.Groups["contents"].Value;`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a regexp like that:

```
abc.*xyz
```

It'll match strings like that:

```
abcblablablaxyz
```

Consider using a minimal match:

```
abc.*?xyz
```

This will only match up to the first xyz, instead of searching up to the last one.

Answer (score 0):

^yourString&

^ - means start of your string
& - end of your string